# SOAP connection and I have a query - Select from array of IDs via SOAP

Tags: soql, soap-api, query

I have a SOAP connection to SFDC in PHP and I have a query that looks like this:

```
$query2 = " Select Name, StartDate from Campaign where Id in (7016F0000025iaJ, 7016F0000025iZV, 7016F000001PvKf)";
```

But I get the following error:

> MALFORMED_QUERY: StartDate from Campaign where Id in (7016F0000025iaJ, 7016F0000025iZV, ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:54 expecting a right parentheses, found 'F0000025iaJ'

I have a list of IDs that I want to query against. What error am I making with my syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the ids in single quotes.

```
WHERE Id IN ('701...', '701...', 'etc.')
```

Answer (score 3):

When you have a specific list of ID values, consider using [`retrieve()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_retrieve.htm) instead:

```
$result = $client->retrieve('Id,Name,StartDate,...','Campaign',array($id1,$id2,...));
```

(note: code above is an example and not meant to be taken literally.)